# Why does my framerate slowly decay while playing Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, framerate

This is a new issue that popped up recently and I have no idea what brought it on.

As I play Skyrim, my FPS will slowly degrade over 15 minutes or so to unplayable levels, but only in certain areas, upon leaving areas with low framerate, my FPS will jump back up again, but returning to the area with bad framerate, results in continued decay.

For example, if I wait in a bad area for about 15 minutes my framerate will fall to about 18. If I return to that area, it will go back to 18. If I enter a different bad area, it will also be at 18 there too. If it continues to fall in that bad area to say, 8 frames/second, and I go to another bad area, the frame rate will jump back down to 8 again.

I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried the lowest possible graphics settings, removing all mods, and reinstalling Skyrim.

I don't believe this is a hardware issue, as everything appears stable in every benchmark, and diagnostic I have run. This issue is isolated to Skyrim. I have tried all advice given to me on installing mods, editing my ini's, and cleaning my mods to no avail.

If anyone has any idea, please help me, as I don't want to have to reinstall the whole OS to eliminate my problem.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any programs running in the background which could be memory leaking or just taking up all the memory

Comment: i usually have nmm running in the background, but the problem persists, even when i do not

Comment: I'd open up Windows task manager and look at the processes tab, see if there is a program/process running in the background, on my work computer Symantec CMC Smc, after 16 days has a commit size of 13+ GB despite it's Memory (Private Working Set) sitting around 26 MB, and of cause Symantec CMC Smc is a Virus Scanner

Comment: i don't see any memory hungry processes running. would it help if i disable all non-essential processes, aside from tesv.exe?

Comment: wouldn't hurt if there is a lot, chrome opens a new process for every single tab so while each of my chrome processes don't use a lot of memory, only about 40MB, but 83 of them is a little over 3 GB in total. you might have a lot of little non-essential processes running taking up all the memory

Comment: ok. ill give it a try. do you know what the essential processes are for windows 7 home edition 64 bit?

Comment: Let me guess - Windows 8.1 on a laptop with an intel cpu and an nvidia gpu? And you run the game at a non-desktop resolution?

Comment: windows 7, i have a tower, with an and 6 core cpu, evga geforce gtx 770, 8 gigs ram...

Comment: I actually misread some of the information, doesn't seem like the problem I was thinking of...

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? It seems like some memory leakage happening in certain areas.

Comment: I'm currently trying to isolate the mod that could be causing this.the process is slow, and I'm not even sure a mod is to blame

Comment: @Garbonshio nope, it's start with looking at the descriptions for any process which was not started by SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SERVICE, anything you do recognize and know it's not essential (ie. Java) is probably safe to close off but i wouldn't really know, i rarely do it

Comment: @Memor-X, alright. ill give it a try. and ill let you know in a few minutes.

Comment: do you guys know if safety load could cause anything like this?

Comment: also, what exactly is a memory leak, and can you tell if you have one?

Comment: @Garbonshio to my understanding, a Memory Leak is when a program/process doesn't release unused allocated memory properly freeing it for other programs/processes and then when it goes to allocate more memory, rather than using what's already allocated but unused it takes up more and allocated memory can't be used between programs. this then snowballs taking in more and more memory and but releasing that's not being used. eg. a Virus Scan when it updates gets allocated memory to do an update but doesn't free it when it's done and gets more allocated memory for the next update, rinse and repeat

Comment: Ideally, memory leak is when a process is using more and more memory over time, instead of properly clearing it when it's not needed (@Memor-X explained it better). The only way to check that would be by logging memory usage, because with games, sometimes alt-tabbing out of it might actually clear the memory.
In this case, if it's not a memory leak, it might be some mod, doing something in an infinite loop, eating the cpu power more and more, which wouldn't be a memory leak, but still just as bad.

Comment: In terms of a Games like Skyrim Mod's would be the easy suspect as per @Chippies initial suspicion, because Memory Leaks are caused by crap "shoot-them-in-the-face-for-just-being-stupid" programming however you can get programs like this too

Comment: *shoot-them-in-the-face-for-just-being-stupid eg.* a User pressing the Print button 500 times when the Printer isn't working and calls Help Desk when the Printer is dying because it's been throwing up paper for the past 10 minutes!

Comment: update: the problem persists, with no mods (only the official update (most recent) and dlc.

Comment: and the problem persists, with all nonessential processes turned off

Comment: SUCESS! ok i found out what was wrong: hdt physics extensions was causing it. whodathunk

Comment: That does sound like something that could do an infinite loop of increasing processing difficulty if programmed wrong. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Please write an answer with the solution an accept it.

Answer (score 2):

To show other readers the possible answers:
*The issue here was that the HDT Physics Extensions was causing clashes as he/she played the game. This has lead to the slowdown over time*